# SwiftUI Programatically Scroll to Bottom of List's Section (or to any particular view)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a complex view that consists of a list with a series of sections. Each section contains elements that are editable, some of these show wheelpickers and all show save and cancel buttons.

The issue I have is that when taps to start editing, the picker and Save/Cancel buttons appear off/below screen and the user has to scroll down to make them visible.

Is there a way to make it so the view will scroll down automatically to make the bottom of a section visible? Can we just have the view scroll to any particular view (e.g. can I ask the view to scroll and anchor to my save/cancel buttons)?

This is the general way I have my view set up

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        if let _ = viewModel.user {
            List {
                Section {}
                Section {}
                Section {}
            }
        else {
        //View shown when loading or when viewModel.user is not found
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of one of my sections

```
Section {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Notes")
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                //button
                            } label: {
                                //label
                            }
                            
                        }
                        TextField("Enter your notes here", text: $notes, axis: .vertical)
                        
                        if notesEditIsActive {
                            SaveCancelButtonView { // *** I want the view to scroll down to make this visible
                                Task {
                                    //save logic
                                }
                            } cancelAction: {
                                //Cancel action
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have tried to embed the list into a scroll view and give each section an ID, then use scroll.scrollTo(ID, anchor) but no luck.

Searching online seems that theres no API to do this with list but instead each view should be in a scrollview and a lazyVStack, is that the case?

Disclaimer: I'm a self taught novice with coding & swift

Thanks

Comment: you need to put list in a scrollview, and use scrollPRoxy to scroll to particular element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let bottomId = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                Button {
                    proxy.scrollTo(bottomId)
                } label: {
                    Text("Goto bottom")
                }
                
                Text("bottom")
                    .id(bottomId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```